# Video recorder per process

Tags: windows, screen-recording

I wonder if there is some open source project with an API that can record video of a specific Windows process, even if this application is not in foreground.

My intention is being able to record multiple browser processes running on the same machine.

Comment: Which processes do you want to monitor? Don't they have logs? If they do isn't just viewing logs enough?

Comment: @onurcano22 Unfortunately logs are not enough in my case. I am running some automated tests on remote VMs and often it is almost impossible to gain sufficient information just by looking at the logs. The processes are browsers, as mentioned in the question

Comment: in their site it says "WM Capture is the only screen capture software that allows you to screen capture video from windows that are minimized or hidden." http://wmrecorder.com/products/wm-capture/ Sorry, an open source alternative doesn't seem to be available.